# How to invert the predicate here?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, predicate, function-composition

I have the following filter procedure:

```
; (2) filter
(define (filter test sequence)
  ; return a list of the elements that pass the predicate test
  (let ((elem (if (null? sequence) nil (car sequence)))
        (rest (if (null? sequence) nil (cdr sequence))))
    (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
          ((test elem) (cons elem (filter test rest)))
          (else (filter test rest)))))
```

And here would be an example of using it to return the even-numbered elements of a list:

```
(define even? (lambda (x) (= (modulo x 2) 0)))
(define sequence '(1 2 3 4 5 8 9 11 13 14 15 16 17))
(filter even? sequence)
; (2 4 8 14 16)
```

Is there a simple way to use the `not` test to invert the selection? For example, I thought the following might work:

```
(filter (not even?) sequence)
```

But it returns an error. I can define `odd` separately, of course:

```
(define odd?  (lambda (x) (not (even? x))))
```

But I'm trying not to do this. Is there a way to write the `odd` procedure without defining it directly, but instead using the `not` directly like I'm trying to do above?

Comment: I feel your pain, but you really have to use Scheme like Scheme. `nil` is not the empty list in Scheme.  When `(null? sequence)` is true, you want to return `()`. Well, no you can't have that either, because it's not self-evaluating; you must quote it: `'()`.

Comment: Removing either matching or non-matching items from a list are very common operations. I would avoid forcing the programmer to compose awkward negations and simply provide both `keep-if` and `remove-if` function.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`complement`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_comple.htm) function in Common Lisp that does what I think you are looking for. `complement` is a higher-order procedure that takes a procedure as its argument, and returns a procedure that takes the same arguments as the input procedure and performs the same actions, but the returned truth value is inverted.

Racket has a similar procedure, [`negate`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=negate#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._negate%29%29), and it is easy enough to implement this in Scheme:

```scheme
(define (complement f)
  (lambda xs (not (apply f xs))))
```

```
> (filter even? '(1 2 3 4 5))
(2 4)
> (filter (complement even?) '(1 2 3 4 5))
(1 3 5)
> (> 1 2 3 4 5)
#f
> ((complement >) 1 2 3 4 5)
#t
```

And in Racket:

```
scratch.rkt> (filter even? '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(2 4)
scratch.rkt> (filter (negate even?) '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(1 3 5)
scratch.rkt> (> 1 2 3 4 5)
#f
scratch.rkt> ((negate >) 1 2 3 4 5)
#t
```

Answer (score 4):

The general answer to this is to simply compose `not` and the function you care about.  Racket has a `compose` function which does this, but you can easily write a simple one yourself:

```
(define (compose-1 . functions)
  ;; simple-minded compose: each function other than the last must
  ;; take just one argument; all functions should return just one
  ;; value.
  (define (compose-loop fns)
    (cond
      ((null? fns)
       (λ (x) x))
      ((null? (cdr fns))
       (car fns))
      (else
       (λ (x) ((car fns) ((compose-loop (cdr fns)) x))))))
  (compose-loop functions))
```

Making it efficient and more general takes more work of course.

Then you can define `odd?` (which is already defined of course):

```
(define odd? (compose-1 not even)
```

Or in fact define a more general CL-style `complement` function:

```
(define (complement f)
  (compose-1 not f))
```

Comment: thanks, out of curiosity, what is the advantage of the function you have vs the one I wrote in the answer above it? Is the main thing that it does all the null checks, or what would be an example of where yours works but mine would fail?

Comment: @David542: my `compose-1` will compose *any* single-argument-single-value functions: `(compose-1 zero? (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))`, say, will return a function which will tell you if its argument is -1 (OK, there are easier ways to to do that).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write an `invert` function which will curry things along (so the initial function still accepts one argument) until the final evaluation occurs:

```
(define invert (lambda (func) (lambda (x) (not (func x)))))
(define sequence '(1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 11 13 14 15 16 17))
(filter (invert even?) sequence)
; (1 3 5 9 11 13 15 17)
```

Comment: A disadvantage of this definition for `invert` is that it only works for unary procedures. That is, this will work for `even?`, but it won't work, e.g., for `<` or `>`. I showed this example in my answer: `((negate >) 1 2 3 4 5)` --> `#t`, but `((invert >) 1 2 3 4 5)` --> arity mismatch. Both CL `complement`, Racket `negate`, and the Scheme definition for `complement` that I showed can operate on n-ary procedures.

Comment: @adabsurdum ah, ok, thanks for pointing that all out!